# Picketlink version needed compatible with Jboss-eap 7.0

Tags: jboss, picketlink

Can anyone tell me which latest picketlink version that is compatible with Jboss-eap 7.0 server?

For Jboss-eap 7.0, I tried configuring my application with picketlink (core-2.7.1)  but found out that picketlink is merged with keycloak.
Currently, I am able to run Picketlink (core-2.5.5) with Jboss-eap 6.2, but I need to update the softwares to their latest version.
Which picketlink version can I use with Jboss-eap 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the version of picketlink used by JBoss EAP 7.0 by having a look inside its module directory at:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/picketlink/core/main/
```

where $JBOSS_HOME is the install directory for `jboss-eap-7.0`:

```
[steve@steves-mbp jboss-eap-7.0]$ ls -l modules/system/layers/base/org/picketlink/core/main/
total 192
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 steve  staff   2063 18 Apr  2016 module.xml
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 steve  staff  93343 18 Apr  2016 picketlink-impl-2.5.5.SP1-redhat-1.jar
```